# Failed Update data with GraphQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, react-native, apollo

Right now im trying to update existing data width

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        updateUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLID },
                email: { type: GraphQLString },
            },
            resolve(parent, { id, email }) {
                console.log('email',email)
                const user = User.findById(id)
                user.email = email
                return user
            }
        },
    }
})
```

my mutation is as this

```
 mutation{
   updateUser(id:"5beac69c421c6e2820a0e809", email:"8"){
       id       
        email
   }

 }
```

What im getting back is the user data, 
but no change has been made in the database please help

Comment: have you forgot to call use.save() somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

@Matan, are you using `Mongoose`? If you are, you have to actually update this data, what you are doing is simply mutating the object and returning it.

With `MongoDB` (if you are using it), you could do it: `User.findOneAndUpdate({ id }, { email })` or close to that.

If it's another DB you have to call a `.save()` or `.update()` at some point, otherwise, you won't change any data.